# JavaFX Changing cell to icon

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have an issue with changing cell to an icon with the following code:

```
    TableColumn typeCol = new TableColumn("Account Type");
           typeCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Account, String>, TableCell<Account, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Account, String> call(TableColumn<Account, String> param) {
            TableCell<Account,String> cell = new TableCell<Account, String>(){
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Account item, boolean empty){
                    if (item != null){
                        VBox vb = new VBox();
                        vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                        ImageView imgVw = new ImageView(item.getTypeIcon());
                        imgVw.setFitHeight(10);
                        imgVw.setFitWidth(10);
                        vb.getChildren().addAll(imgVw);
                        setGraphic(vb);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
    typeCol.setMinWidth(100);
    typeCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Account, String>("type"));
```

The issue here is that for some reason I get en error of 'method does not override or implement a method form a supertype'. Any idaes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TableCell<S, T>` extends `Cell<T>`, not `Cell<S>`. Therefore the correct signature for the [`updateItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-) method of `TableCell<Account, String>` is

```
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
```

---

Assuming your `cellValueFactory`

```
new PropertyValueFactory<Account, String>("type")
```

returns `ObservableValue`s containing the URLs of images, you can use

```
ImageView imgVw = new ImageView(item);
```

instead of

```
ImageView imgVw = new ImageView(item.getTypeIcon());
```

Since the value passed to the `updateItem` method is the one that is contained in the `ObservableValue` returned by the `cellValueFactory`.

Comment: How can I have access to the methods of my object in the updateItem method?

Comment: @uksz: see my edit. Basically the `cellValueFactory` selects part of item to be used and the cell returned by `cellFactory` displays that data (in this case as image).

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for placing an image in a table cell:

```
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;

public class ImageTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, Image> {
    private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

    public ImageTableCell() {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            imageView.setImage(null);
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        imageView.setImage(item);
        setGraphic(imageView);
    }
}
```

This will work fine if your table doesn't represent millions of items.  If you have many items and can't hold all of the potential images in memory, then you would need a TableCell instead of TableCell where the string is just the URL of the image rather than the actual image data itself.  Then you would keep an LRU cache of image data which you would update in the updateItem, fetching the image data from the cache if it was there, otherwise loading it from the url.  Such an approach could get a little tricky as you would probably want to be careful not to do too much dynamic loading of images as the user scrolls.  In general, if you just have a few hundred or thousand thumbnail images, then the straight-forward approach defined in the code above would suffice rather than the alternate cache based approach.